# Configure network to have good multiplex

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have some Macs connected to the internet through a Netgear router.
All use a wireless connection.

I also have an AirPlay speaker connected wirelessly to the same router.

A smart TV is also connected by ethernet.

When I watch a video from the internet on a Mac and someone streams a video from another Mac to the TV, nothing works fine. The video from the internet lags and the TV video stream lags too.

I think the problem doesn't come from the internet connection because all is in the local network.

I already put down the MTU to 1450 to avoid packet collisions.
The wireless (5GHz) channel is 40 and I'm the only person to use it in the building.

What can be wrong in the router config?

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you could add some more 'academic' data. Try if file transfers have the same problem, note which throughput you get and what the latency is (using a host on the internet).

Comment: When I download a file from internet (try with ubuntu img), I download with 3-4Mo/s without interuption BUT it freezes websites, videos or others things. I feel that the router can't manage several big flows in same time.

Comment: If that is the case you should see a high CPU load on the router, do you see that?

Comment: I didn't think to look that. I look at this asap

Comment: I can't watch cpu on my router :(

Comment: I could help you calculate your airtime usage if you could tell me what data rates the the Macs are connecting at during this test. Option-click on the Wi-Fi Menu Extra on each of your Macs to see what your transmit rate is. For the Mac receiving the Internet video stream, what transmit rate does the Netgear AP report when sending to that Mac? Also, do you have any idea what protocol you are using to stream from the other Mac to the smart TV?

Comment: The protocol is DLNA. I use serviio on the mac and I stream on the TVA via the DLNA protocol.

Comment: Where I can find this menu ? In diagnosis tool, I see throughput but I'm not sure it's what you want. This throughput is 1300Mbps for the mac which download (weird) and 450 for others